# How to pass arguments to rules_event?

Tags: rules

```
rules_invoke_event('example_entry_add',$user,$result);

 function warden_rules_event_info() {

 dd("Event info");

   return array(
     'example_entry_add' => array(
       'label' => t('An entry has been added'),
       'module' => 'example',
       'variables'=>array(
         'user' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('user')),
         'entry' => array('type' => 'entry', 'label' => t('entry')),
     ),
       'group' => t('example'),
     ),   );

 }
```

I have a question, when I add an entry to a user I want to invoke an event (rules_invoke_event ('example_entry_add', $ user, $ result);) with two variables that need these variables passed to them rules_event function, but how the step after another to function, in this case the rules_condition, can someone help me?, thank you, excuse me for asking, but I'm starting to develop in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rules_invoke_event_by_args`  read details [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_event_by_args/7)

Example:

`rules_invoke_event_by_args('node_view', array('node' => $node, 'view_mode' => $view_mode));`
Also, [this](http://drupalize.me/videos/invoking-rules-events) tutorial may possibly help

Comment: Thank you, already solved the problem by enabling php filter module and this site following this example: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/06/29/drupal-7-create-your-own-rules-event/

I hope it helps anyone who has had my problem.